# Show that a constant function $f(x)=c$ at all points except $a$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ has the value c at all points
>   in the interval $[a,b]$ except at the point $x=a$. Show that f is
>   integrable on $[a,b]$  and its integral equals $c(b-a)$.

**My attempt:**
Let $P_n=\{a=x_0,...,x_n=b\}$ be a regular partition of $[a,b]$, i.e. $x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac{b-a}{n}$, and let $f(a)=d,$ so $$f(x)=\begin{cases} c,x \in (a,b] \\ d, x=a \end{cases}.$$ Then $M_i=sup\{f(x)|x \text{ in } [x_{i-1},x_i]\}=c, i=2,...,n,$ and $m_i=inf\{f(x)|x \text{ in } [x_{i-1},x_i]\}=c, i=2,...,n.$ 

 For $[x_0,x_1]\ M_1=\max(c,d), m_1=\min(c,d).$ Therefore,
$$L(f,P_n)=\min(c,d)\frac{b-a}{n} + \sum_{i=2}^nc\frac{b-a}{n}=(\min(c,d)+c)\frac{b-a}{n}n=(\min(c,d)+c)(b-a).$$ Similarly,
$U(f,P_n)=(\max(c,d)+c)(b-a).$

In order to prove that $f$ is integrable, I need to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L(f,P_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}U(f,P_n),$ but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas and suggestions? I would appreciate any explicit solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $ \min (c,d) \frac {b-a} n \to 0$ and $ \max (c,d) \frac {b-a} n \to 0$.

Comment: I think I found a mistake in my proof, it should be $L(f,P_n)=\min(c,d)\frac{b-a}{n} + \sum_{i=2}^nc\frac{b-a}{n}=\min(c,d)\frac{b-a}{n}+c(n-1)\frac{b-a}{n}$ and if we take limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L(f,P_n)=c(b-a)$. Similarly, we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}U(f,P_n)=c(b-a)$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L(f,P_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}U(f,P_n)=c(b-a)$, the integral equals to $c(b-a)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @dxdydz yes, it is correct.